# How to send Hyperlink with spaces in Sendgrid

Tags: sendgrid-api-v3, sendgrid-templates

I use sendgrid service for my application for sending email.
In the email, I am sending a hyperlink that contains space.

`<a href={{here}}>here</a>`

`here = https://example.org/transport/?user=sam&type=bus ac&org=abc`

In query parameters with type, I'm getting it from the scroll selector.

when I get the mail the hyperlink is navigating only till
`https://example.org/transport/?user=sam&type=bus`

Is there a way I could navigate to the provided URL?

Comment: That's not a valid link. You must encode your whitespace as `%20` ie `...&type=bus%20ac...`

Comment: @derpirscher It worked, I use python used it as `urllib.parse.quote(type)`